Minimal polynomial of a recurrent sequence
Let $u$ ${\in}$ ${F^{\infty} _{2}}$ be a linear recurrent sequence with an irreducible characteristic polynomial f(x). Find the minimal polynomial of the sequence $\bar{u}$, where
$\bar{u}$ is the complement of the sequence $u$ ($\bar{u}$ = $u$ + 1).

Could you state (or give an online link for) the definition of the characteristic and minimal polynomial of a sequence?

I suspect that, if the defining recurrence is given by $\sum_{j=0}^n a_ju_{k+j} = 0$, then the associated characteristic polynomial is $p(x) = \sum_{j=0}a_j x^j$. Can you at least state whether this is the case?

Note that there is a trivial case here: if the sequence is non-zero and the characteristic polynomial of the sequence is $f(x) = x+1$, then $\bar u$ is the zero-sequence and it's not clear what the minimal polynomial of the sequence should be in this case

For any other characteristic polynomial, assuming that I have the correct definition of a "minimal polynomial" in mind and assuming that $u \neq 0$, $(x+1)f(x)$ should end up being the minimal polynomial of $\bar u$.

@BenGrossmann ${(x + 1)f(x)}$ does not work in case ${f(x) = x^{2}}$. A polynomial is minimal for a linear recurrent sequence if it is characteristic and of minimal degree. Also minimal polynomial m has the property: ${m(x)|f(x)}$

What does it mean for a polynomial to "be characteristic"? Also, $f(x)$ is not an irreducible polynomial, but I suppose that your point applies for the polynomial $f(x) = x$ as well.

@BenGrossmann You correctly specified the definition of a characteristic polynomial
